# Mysql Full Text relevance between two tables

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

Hello all I ask help regarding use of Full text in mysql.
I have two tables.
One where there are keywords and another where there are other keywords.
I would like to create a relevance between the two joining tables getting the highest importance.
For example if in a table I as the keyword "A, B, C", "B, A, F" and in the other I "B, C, D" I would like to obtain in a single table from me as a result the relevance between these two tabelle.I hope I was as clear as possible.

Table A

```
+------------+------------+
| id         |  keyword1  |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | A,B,C      |
| 2          | B,A,F      |
+------------+------------+
```

Table B

```
+------------+------------+
| id         |  keyword2  |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | B,C,D      |
+------------+------------+
```

I Use this sql code:

```
SELECT id,keyword1, 
    MATCH (B.keyword2) AGAINST (+'B,C,D' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance1   
         FROM B
    UNION
     SELECT id,keyword2, 
    MATCH (B.keyword2) AGAINST (+'B,C,D' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance1
    FROM B
    WHERE (MATCH (A.keyword1) AGAINST (+'B,C,D' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
    ORDER BY (Relevance1) DESC
```

I want the result like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| id         |  keyword2  |   keyword1  |  Relevance1 |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1          | B,C,D      |   A,B,C     |  0,1213     |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2          | B,C,D      |  B,A,F      !  0,01234    |
+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide the table structures and some example data from both tables... and a example of expected result.

Comment: I edited the post hope I was clear

Comment: you won't be able to achieve this with a single `SELECT` query because `AGAINST()` requires explicit string value, table column reference will not work.

Comment: I changed my table with a join to obtain the result that interested me thank you all for the answers.if interested i post the table.